# Can class and struct be used interchangeably in template specialization?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Can I use the keyword `struct` to specialize a template class declared with the keyword `class`? Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example:

```
template <class T>
class X {};

template <>
struct X<int> {};  // explicit specialization (full specialization)

template <class T>
struct X<X<T>> {}; // partial specialization
```

This code compiles on [GCC 8.3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oKN9q68HMwznqYEF) and [Clang 8.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8YiVw8nhVQhXLPNZ).

What is the standard's take on this? A quote from the standard with explanation is appreciated.

Comment: In theory you could do something like `class specialX : public x<int>` to get what you want, I think. Not sure about doing it that way, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid.

[temp.class]/4:

> In a redeclaration, partial specialization, explicit specialization or
>   explicit instantiation of a class template, the *class-key* shall
>   agree in kind with the original class template declaration
>   ([dcl.type.elab]).

[dcl.type.elab]/3 defines "agree in kind":

> The *class-key* or enum keyword present in the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* shall agree in kind with the declaration to which the name in the *elaborated-type-specifier* refers. [...]
>   Thus, in any *elaborated-type-specifier*, the `enum` keyword shall be
>   used to refer to an enumeration ([dcl.enum]), the `union` *class-key*
>   shall be used to refer to a union ([class]), and either the `class` or
>   `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a class ([class])
>   declared using the `class` or `struct` *class-key*.